# Parameter passing causes an error when using go_router

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I can't access state.queryParameters during routing with Go router. In the doc the following example is given:

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/users',
  builder: (context, state) => const UsersScreen(filter: state.queryParameters['filter']),
)
```

Here's how I implemented the whole thing:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(    
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
          path: "/",
          builder: (context, state) => const Dashboard(),
          routes: [
       
        // 1. pathParameter
        GoRoute(path: "profile/:name", builder: (context, state) => Profile(
          name: state.pathParameters["name"]!
        )),
        // 2. queryParameter
        GoRoute(path: "settings", builder: (context, state) => Settings(
            name: state.queryParameters['name']!
        )),
      ]),
    ]
  );
```

While it works fine with pathParameter, state.queryParameters cannot be accessed. I get following error message: `Error: The getter 'queryParameters' isn't defined for the class 'GoRouterState'.`

I use `go_router: 10.1.2`. Does anyone know what to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a breaking change with the latest go_router packages which replaces accessing the location, queryParamters, and queryParameterAll with uri

so instead of accessing the queryParamters like this

```
GoRoute(path: "profile/:name", builder: (context, state) => Profile(
  name: state.pathParameters["name"]!
)),
state.queryParameters['name']!
```

it has been replaced with this

```
GoRoute(path: "profile/:name", builder: (context, state) => Profile(
  name: state.uri.queryParameters["name"]!
)),
```

you can read more about it here [go_router_migration_guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vjupshmFJtfGSOppZxp7Tzkq7dotcLxCcpdluuNYe1o/edit?resourcekey=0-aS66t4OcDTjJW50s-veSzQ)

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. :)

It's still annoying that the developers don't adjust this in their documentation. People who are new in the field may spend hours on such problem. Whereas now at least here they find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a breaking [change on go_router v10](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vjupshmFJtfGSOppZxp7Tzkq7dotcLxCcpdluuNYe1o/edit?resourcekey=0-aS66t4OcDTjJW50s-veSzQ).

You need to change like

```dart
builder: (context, state) {
       final Map<String, String> queryParameters = GoRouterState.of(context).uri.queryParameters;
```